# Can't connect to Derby using DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties) with authentication enabled

Tags: java, derby

I started the Derby Network Server, and am able to connect it using these two methods:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://192.168.1.1:1527//opt/db", "user", "password");
```

and

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://192.168.1.1:1527//opt/db" + ";user=user;password=password");
```

However, I can't connect using the following:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", "user");
props.put("password", "password");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://192.168.1.1:1527//opt/db", props);
```

Is there something that I am missing? Or the third way is not supported by Derby?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

The third method is working properly, must have been some typo previously. Sorry about that.